# Passing a parameter to ant from CruiseControl Dashboard

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol

I am working on incorporating CruiseControl into my teams build process.  What we need is a way to pass a Clearcase view name into the ant script so it knows what view to use when building.  Sometimes a developer needs to create a build that is used for their testing only and not on the main integration branch.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Absolutely.  At a previous job I worked on a project where developed a highly customizable build solution where people could request all sorts of parameters.  You should just be able to create an additional Cruise Control project which does what you're asking no?  That seems really simple so I'm guessing I'm missing something from your inquiry.  I haven't used ClearCase before but I've done what you are asking so I know its possible.

This may be a question better suited for the Cruise Control mailing list (http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/contact.html).

Comment: I think what MSUDrew means is to add a parameter to a build ad-hoc so that it just passes it in for one run. Is that right?